# How do I calculate route distance between many GeoJSON points in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, database

How do I calculate route distance between many GeoJSON points in MongoDB? Can I have a database query that sort items by their date field, then calculates the distance between points and finally sums all of then to calculate the total distance?

Here are some examples of my data:

```
{ 
 _id: 599cfc236ed0d81c98007f66
 tracerId: 59a07ea26ed0d81d78001acd
 loc { 
      type: "2dsphere",
      coordinates: [ 159.9, -37.92 ]
     },
 date: 2017-08-26 00:16:42,
 speed: 58,
}
{ 
 _id: 59a074d46ed0d81d78001acc
 tracerId: 59a07ea26ed0d81d78001acd
 loc { 
      type: "2dsphere",
      coordinates: [ 160, -38.20 ]
     },
 date: 2017-08-26 00:18:42,
 speed: 75,
}
{ 
 _id: 59a074d46ed0d81d78ac11cc
 tracerId: 59a07ea26ed0d81d78001acd
 loc { 
      type: "2dsphere",
      coordinates: [ 160.222, -38.92 ]
     },
 date: 2017-08-26 00:20:42,
 speed: 60,
}
```

Comment: Yes. (1) sort items by date field (2) calculate distance between points  (3) sum all of them to calculate route distance. Try looking for these individually and comeback with what doesn't work.

Comment: @nullpointer thanks for your answer, for separate query for each step i can do step 1 and 2 but have no Idea for step 3.
But the real issue is I want performance so isn't there any way I can do all with one query.

Comment: Once you are done with all three, we can think of performance then, right? Don't want to be puzzling, share what's working, what's not working, what performance issues you're facing(such details) in the question to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments as well, would try to draw a similar picture here using Java. Assuming your database name `db` and collection name as `col` and the document type as `GeoData` which could be modelled as :

```
public class GeoData {
    String tracerId;
    Location loc;
    Date date;
    Integer speed;
    ...getters, setters and other overrides
}

public class Location {
    String type;
    Coordinate coordinates;
}

public class Coordinate {
    double x;
    double y;
}
```

It would proceed as follows :

1. Sort items by date field (let's say in ascending order)

   ```
   MongoDatabase database = getDatabase("db");
   MongoCollection<GeoData> collection = database.getCollection("col", GeoData.class);
   Bson sortFilter = Filters.eq("date", "1"); //sort ascending
   List<GeoData> geoData = Lists.newArrayList(collection.find().sort(sortFilter));
   ```
2. Calculate the distance between points using `c = square root of [(xA-xB)^2+(yA-yB)^2]`

   ```
   private static double distanceBetweenCoordinates(Coordinate a, Coordinate b) {
       return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.getX() - a.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(b.getY() - a.getY(),2));
   }
   ```
3. Sum all of them to calculate route distance

   ```
   double routeDist = 0.0;
   for (int i = 0; i < geoData.size()-1; i++) {
       routeDist += distanceBetweenCoordinates(geoData.get(i+1).getLoc().getCoordinates(), geoData.get(i+1).getLoc().getCoordinates());
   }
   ```